# Erro ao fazer verificação no IF com array no PHP

Tags: php, array, if

Estou tentando fazer um `if` dentro de um `foreach` e a situação está sendo a seguinte:

Tenho um `array` que chamei de **$matriculas** que retorna assim:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["chave"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["chave"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

E eu tentei este código:

```
foreach($matriculas as $matricula){
        if(in_array($row['id_curso'],$matricula)){
            echo '<a href="" class="btn btn-success disabled">Matriculado</a>';
        }else{
            echo 'nois';
        }
    }
```

Eu gostaria de mostrar a informação caso o valor de `$row['id_curso']` exista em `$matricula`, se não existir ele deveria mostrar um botão qualquer.O problema é que ele exibe os dois, ou seja, existindo `$row['id_curso']` em `$matriculas` ou não existindo.Existe uma maneira de corrigir isto?

Comment: Você não precisa iterar o `array $matriculas` com o `foreach` a função `in_array` já verifica se existe ou não!

Comment: @IgorMello se eu não usar o foreach ele não encontra porque o array é Multi dimensional... Se fosse um array simples rodaria!

Comment: erro meu, não tinha percebido isto. Fiz uma possível solução dá uma olhada!

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na lógica. Está a "imprimir" os dois resultados pelo fato de seu `array` ser multidimensional, então para cada `array` interno ele testa o `if/else` mesmo o valor já tendo sido achado na primeira iteração, ele vai fazer o teste até acabar os `arrays` internos.

**Aqui tem uma possível solução:**

```
$matriculas = array(array('chave'=>1), array('chave'=>3));
$row['id_curso'] = 3;
$saida = false;

foreach($matriculas as $matricula){
    if(!$saida)
        $saida = (in_array($row['id_curso'],$matricula));
}
echo ($saida == 1) ? '<a href="" class="btn btn-success disabled">Matriculado</a>' : 'qualquer coisa';
```

Usei uma variável auxiliar chamada `$saida` para controlar. Ela inicia com `false`. Então para cada volta do `foreach` faço o teste para ver se "achou" algo, pois se ela receber `true`(achou o elemento) é porque já não precisa mais fazer o teste.

Comment: Isso, eu testei justamente esse caso... Se não declarasse o valor da saida (que receberia True caso encontrasse) como false, ele marcaria todas os cursos como matriculado, Você tem razão!

Comment: É assim com está variável faz o controle do `foreach`, até quando ele tem que procurar o _elemento_ no `array`!

Answer (score 2):

Assim funcionaria também!

```
$matriculas = array(array('chave'=>1), array('chave'=>3));

    foreach($matriculas as $obj){
        foreach ($obj as $value){
            if($value == $row['id_curso']){
                echo '<a href="" class="btn btn-success disabled">Matriculado</a>';
            }
            elseif ($value =! $row['id_curso']){
                echo 'nois';
            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é, pra cada item na lista ele checa, então ele vai ver lá, a array tem 1, 3, 5, 7. ele pega o elemento id 5

ele vai passar falando, nao, nao, sim, nao.
O que voce precisa fazer é achar o elemento ali dentro com o loop, e sair do loop com a informação se achou ou não, dai então tomar ação.

```
foreach($chaves as $arrayChaves){
    if(in_array($row['chave'],$arrayChaves, false)){
        achou = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($achou) {
    echo '<a href="" class="btn btn-success disabled">Matriculado</a>';
}else{
    echo 'nois';
}
```

Assim funcionou perfeitamente, mas obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Comment: Colocar `break` pode até ter funcionado, porém não é uma boa prática!

Comment: Certo, no caso, eu só usei o Break pra forçar ele a parar ali e retornar ao inicio passar ao próximo personagem do foreach...

Answer (score 0):

Testei o seguinte código e trabalhou da forma correta:

```
<?php
$matriculas = array(array('chave'=>1), array('chave'=>3));

foreach($matriculas as $matricula){
        if(in_array(1,$matricula)){
            echo 'Encontrado';
        }else{
            echo 'Não Encontrado';
        }
    }
?>
```

No seu caso:

```
<?php
$matriculas = array(array('chave'=>1), array('chave'=>3));

foreach($matriculas as $matricula){
        if(in_array($row['id_curso'],$matricula)){
            echo 'Encontrado';
        }else{
            echo 'Não Encontrado';
        }
    }
?>
```

Caso não dê, verifique o valor de `$row['id_curso']` se está correto.

O conteúdo de `$matriculas` tem que ser um `array` ? Pois pode existir outras formas de fazer o que você precisa.

Comment: não funcionou, na verdade eu poderia retornar como um objeto, eu trouxe como uma array por ser o padrão que estou usando nesse projeto... Poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso usando objetos?

Só mias um detalhe, ele funciona da forma correta, o problema é que está imprimindo tanto o valor se positivo do `IF` quando o valor negativo, E fica assim, por exemplo "ENCONTRADOnãoENCONTRADO" entende? e no que não encontra ele diz "NÂO ENCONTRADONÃO ENCONTRADO"